# Ruby map JSON into Ruby Class -Can't convert string to Integer

Tags: ruby, json, rhomobile

New to JSON/RUBY.
I have a Rest Service returning a JSON string and I would like to parse this into a Ruby Class. Is this recommended? I have tried the following example and get error- Can't convert String to Integer. This is for a rhomobile app I'm working on. I'm thinking POJO-->JSON-->Ruby. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
Ruby

  @@get_result = @params['body']
     puts "@@get_result : #{@@get_result}"

     data2 =@@get_result

     cust1 = data2["PolicyList"].map { |rd| PolicyList.new(rd["policyNbr"], rd["systemId"], rd["insuredName"], 
                      rd["type"], rd["statusCd"], rd["statusDes"], rd["payorZipcode"], 
                      rd["lastPaymentDate"], rd[lastPaymentAmount], rd["pastDueDate"], rd["pastDueAmount"], 
                      rd["currentDueDate"], rd["currentDueAmount"], rd["eft"], 
                      rd["suspenseAmt"], rd["expireTime"]) }
```

Class

```
  class PolicyList  
       attr_accessor :policyNbr, :systemId, :insuredName,
            :type, :statusCd, :statusDes, :payorZipcode,
            :lastPaymentDate,:lastPaymentAmount,:pastDueDate,
            :pastDueAmount,:currentDueDate,:currentDueAmount,:eft,
            :suspenseAmt,:expireTime


       def initialize(policyNbr,             systemId,insuredName,type,statusCd,statusDes,payorZipcode,lastPaymentDate,lastPaymentAmount,
             pastDueDate,pastDueAmount,currentDueDate,currentDueAmount,eft,suspenseAmt,expireTime)
   @systemId = systemId
   @insuredName = insuredName
   @type = type  
   @statusCd = statusCd  
    @statusDes = statusDes
   @payorZipcode = payorZipcode
   @lastPaymentDate =  lastPaymentDate
   @lastPaymentAmount = lastPaymentAmount
   @pastDueDate = pastDueDate 
   @pastDueAmount = pastDueAmount
   @currentDueDate = currentDueDate
   @currentDueAmount = currentDueAmount
   @eft = eft
   @suspenseAmt = suspenseAmt
   @expireTime = expireTime
  end

 end
```

Returned JSON

```
  [{"policyNbr":"0000001","systemId":"MB","insuredName":"JOHN DOE ","type":"MEMBERSHIP","statusCd":"01","statusDes":"PAID","payorZipcode":"99999","lastPaymentDate":"07/12/2012","lastPaymentAmount":25.00,"pastDueDate":"","pastDueAmount":0.00,"currentDueDate":"","currentDueAmount":0.00,"eft":false,"suspenseAmt":false,"expireTime":1362152384971},{"policyNbr":"0000002","systemId":"PC","insuredName":"JOHN DOE","type":"AUTO","statusCd":"01","statusDes":"PAID","payorZipcode":"99999","lastPaymentDate":"02/15/2013","lastPaymentAmount":308.50,"pastDueDate":"","pastDueAmount":0.00,"currentDueDate":"","currentDueAmount":0.00,"eft":false,"suspenseAmt":false,"expireTime":0},{"policyNbr":"0000003","systemId":"PC","insuredName":"JOHN DOE","type":"HOME","statusCd":"01","statusDes":"PAID","payorZipcode":"99999","lastPaymentDate":"09/05/2012","lastPaymentAmount":149.00,"pastDueDate":"","pastDueAmount":0.00,"currentDueDate":"","currentDueAmount":0.00,"eft":false,"suspenseAmt":false,"expireTime":0}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an array of PolicyList objects, but there is no key called 'PolicyList'. I think you need this:

```
cust1 = data2.map { |rd| PolicyList.new(rd["policyNbr"], rd["systemId"], rd["insuredName"],
                rd["type"], rd["statusCd"], rd["statusDes"], rd["payorZipcode"],
                rd["lastPaymentDate"], rd['lastPaymentAmount'], rd["pastDueDate"], rd["pastDueAmount"],
                rd["currentDueDate"], rd["currentDueAmount"], rd["eft"],
                rd["suspenseAmt"], rd["expireTime"]) }
```

To make it easier for you. Here is a complete example.

```
class PolicyList
     attr_accessor :policyNbr, :systemId, :insuredName,
          :type, :statusCd, :statusDes, :payorZipcode,
          :lastPaymentDate,:lastPaymentAmount,:pastDueDate,
          :pastDueAmount,:currentDueDate,:currentDueAmount,:eft,
          :suspenseAmt,:expireTime


       def initialize(policyNbr,             systemId,insuredName,type,statusCd,statusDes,payorZipcode,lastPaymentDate,lastPaymentAmount,
             pastDueDate,pastDueAmount,currentDueDate,currentDueAmount,eft,suspenseAmt,expireTime)
   @systemId = systemId
   @insuredName = insuredName
   @type = type
   @statusCd = statusCd
    @statusDes = statusDes
   @payorZipcode = payorZipcode
   @lastPaymentDate =  lastPaymentDate
   @lastPaymentAmount = lastPaymentAmount
   @pastDueDate = pastDueDate
   @pastDueAmount = pastDueAmount
   @currentDueDate = currentDueDate
   @currentDueAmount = currentDueAmount
   @eft = eft
   @suspenseAmt = suspenseAmt
   @expireTime = expireTime
  end

end


require 'json'
json = <<-JSON
  [{"policyNbr":"0000001","systemId":"MB","insuredName":"JOHN DOE ","type":"MEMBERSHIP","statusCd":"01","statusDes":"PAID","payorZipcode":"99999","lastPaymentDate":"07/12/2012","lastPaymentAmount":25.00,"pastDueDate":"","pastDueAmount":0.00,"currentDueDate":"","currentDueAmount":0.00,"eft":false,"suspenseAmt":false,"expireTime":1362152384971},{"policyNbr":"0000002","systemId":"PC","insuredName":"JOHN DOE","type":"AUTO","statusCd":"01","statusDes":"PAID","payorZipcode":"99999","lastPaymentDate":"02/15/2013","lastPaymentAmount":308.50,"pastDueDate":"","pastDueAmount":0.00,"currentDueDate":"","currentDueAmount":0.00,"eft":false,"suspenseAmt":false,"expireTime":0},{"policyNbr":"0000003","systemId":"PC","insuredName":"JOHN DOE","type":"HOME","statusCd":"01","statusDes":"PAID","payorZipcode":"99999","lastPaymentDate":"09/05/2012","lastPaymentAmount":149.00,"pastDueDate":"","pastDueAmount":0.00,"currentDueDate":"","currentDueAmount":0.00,"eft":false,"suspenseAmt":false,"expireTime":0}]
JSON


@@get_result = JSON.parse(json)

puts "@@get_result : #{@@get_result}\n\n"

data2 =@@get_result

cust1 = data2.map { |rd| PolicyList.new(rd["policyNbr"], rd["systemId"], rd["insuredName"],
                rd["type"], rd["statusCd"], rd["statusDes"], rd["payorZipcode"],
                rd["lastPaymentDate"], rd['lastPaymentAmount'], rd["pastDueDate"], rd["pastDueAmount"],
                rd["currentDueDate"], rd["currentDueAmount"], rd["eft"],
                rd["suspenseAmt"], rd["expireTime"]) }


puts cust1.inspect
```

Comment: Note I also fixed the lastPaymentDate key (it needed quotes)

Comment: Thanks. I ran your suggestion and got error: uninitialized constant. Is there a problem with  initialize on my PolicyList class and calling the new in the map function?

Comment: what was the uninitialized constant? you are using this in place of the relevant bit of code in your example right?

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant MyAccountController::PolicyList. My PolicyList class is outside this Controller class...

Comment: Ok, that's something completely different from the issue you've explained above. Put the code I just added in a ruby file say example.rb and run with ruby example.rb and your marshalling json problem is sorted. For the MyAccountController bit you probably need to something like require 'policy_list' (assuming PolicyList is in a file called policy_list.rb in lib)

Comment: Changed to ::PolicyList.new and got error e #<NameError: uninitialized constant PolicyList>

Comment: I move policyList into its own folder and required it on the controller and everything worked thanks again.